# Dockable menu item using Jquery

Tags: jquery, dock

I have a requirement very similar as in http://www.webappers.com/2009/06/04/how-to-implement-docking-functionality-with-jquery/

The problem I am facing is that I have a TreeView control inside one of the TABS and the treeview renders as UL and LI on the DOM. I was trying to use a div instead of ul & li as mentioned in the above link, but to find the whole menu is getting messed up. I did try using the other example ["Pin Menu" using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618594/pin-menu-using-jquery) but the problem with this is that the TAB is not moving on the right correctly. Can anyone help me on this ! I am stuck for the last 5 hours on this. I need to have a vertical menu on the left side of the screen and the menu needs to roll over towards right and user can basically dock/undock the menu. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks
Anirban

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using jquery Ui layout

[http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/container_centered.html]

Thanks,
Anirban